# SQL duplication on colA and colB, where colC exists both zero and non-zero value

Tags: sql, database

I have a database relation as such:
House(street, street_number, built_year)

I want to SELECT  entries where exists duplications on both
street and street number,

and exists both zero value and non-zero value on built_year column.

Then for those entries  where street and street number are the same,
 assign non-zero in column built_year to  the column with zero value.

Appreciate for the help. Thanks

Comment: With you until the end, what do you mean "and exists both zero value and non-zero value on built_year column.

Then for those entries where street and street number are the same, assign non-zero in column built_year to the column with zero value."  There can't be two values for 1 column.

Comment: Maybe my description is not clear enough.
In the case where street, street_number are the same, meaning the same building, some entries are lack of built_year recording due to the history issue. So now what I'm trying to do is to overwrite the non-recorded valued with where there exists recorded ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT street, street_number, MAX(built_year) AS maxBuiltYear FROM House GROUP BY street, street_number HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
UPDATE House SET built_year = maxBuiltYear FROM House as h INNER JOIN CTE as c ON c.street = h.street and c.street_number = h.street_number WHERE built_year = 0;
```

The common table expression (CTE) gets all houses that exist more than once considering street and street_number with the highest built_year within those houses that exist more than once. Then you just update those houses whose biult_year is 0 by joining them with the CTE.
Hope it helps.